# jQuery conditional statement within value range clarification

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

Using a drag and drop function with a container that the draggable item needs to be on, or near you would use `IF && statement`.

Just wanted to clarify whether, or not another approach would be better to meet the same game.

Ideally, is there a real way to code something like:

```
If(box.left within(20px) of container.left && box.top within(20px) of container.top) { // do something } else {do something else }
```

Otherwise it will be a lot of code and I am trying to reduce that.  Is this possible ?

**UPDATED**

Full Code:

```
  var letter = document.getElementById('box_' + element.id.substr(element.id.indexOf('_') + 1, 1));
        var home = document.getElementById('answerBox_' + element.id.substr(element.id.indexOf('_') + 1, 1));
        letter = letter.getBoundingClientRect();
        home = home.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(Math.abs(letter.left - home.left) <= 20 && Math.abs(letter.top - home.top ) <= 20) {
 {

        console.log('close enough');
        } else {
        console.log('Not close enough');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs), [*element*.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft), and [*element*.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsettop)

For example:

```
if(Math.abs(box.offsetLeft - container.offsetLeft) <= 20  && 
   Math.abs(box.offsetTop  - container.offsetTop ) <= 20) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Would that check if box was either higher or lower than current cords

Comment: This checks to see if box left is within 20 pixels of container left, *and* if box top is within 20 pixels of container top.  This should be correct syntax for your pseudocode, but it may not completely solve your problem.  Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Thanks @Rick, this did it `if(Math.abs(letter.left - home.left) <= 20 && Math.abs(letter.top - home.top ) <= 20) {
`

Comment: Glad it's working.  You may be able to use offsetLeft and offsetTop directly on the DOM elements instead of getBoundingClientRect().left and top.